# How to get and store a value into a variable from SQL query php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store the result from an sql query into a variable in my php query. But thing is, it is not working, simply because I am making schoolboy errors and due to my lack of experience in php.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['driverNo'])){
        $driverNoText = $_POST['driverNo'];
        $stmt = "SELECT registrationNo FROM cars WHERE driverNo = ?";
        $result = $conn->prepare($stmt);
        $result->bind_param('s', $driverNoText);
        $result->execute();
        $result->store_result();

        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            $registrationNo = $result["registrationNo"];
            echo $registrationNo;
        }
        else{
            $registrationNo = "";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Something went horribly wrong";
    }
?>
```

I just want to store the registrationNo into the $registrationNo, because I need to use that value elsewhere later.

Would mean a lot if someone could help me fix my error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the value incorrectly. It is not an array, try replacing this:

```
$registrationNo = $result["registrationNo"];
```

with this:

```
$registrationNo = $result[0]->registrationNo;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for answering my question, but it still doesn't work. I am getting this error "Cannot use object of type mysqli_stmt as array"

Comment: As there is only one registration number for a driver, the result set should either be 0 or 1 - its just assigning the result to a variable that im stuck on

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an idea where exactly you're facing the issue?

You could try debugging. Try something like this:

```
$stmt = "SELECT registrationNo FROM cars WHERE driverNo = ?";
$result = $conn->prepare($stmt) or die( mysqli_error($dbh) ); // Where $dbh =   mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "password", "database");
$result->bind_param('s', $driverNoText);
$result->execute() or die( mysqli_stmt_error($result) );
//$result->store_result();
/* I'd prefer you to use bind result instead */
$result->bind_result($registrationNo);
echo $registrationNo; // This must show the registration no.
```

Hope this helps.

Peace! xD

Comment: you need to `fetch()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php  Please choose Object-oriented or Procedural syntax, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (for array fetching)

```
<?php
// your codes ...

$result->bind_param('s', $driverNoText);
$result->execute();
$result->bind_result($col);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while ($result->fetch()){
            $registrationNo = $col;
            echo $registrationNo."<br/>";
      }
} else{
      $registrationNo = '';
      echo $registrationNo."<br/>";
}

// your code ...

?>
```

Comment: @BenjMikesozery What errors are you getting? Does the `$_POST['driverNo']` really gets a value? Or maybe there is/are no fetched data at all?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it now, $result is an array holding the entire row of data from your table, but since you're trying to return a single value instead of a complete row, you can just use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT registrationNo FROM cars WHERE driverNo = " . $_POST['driverNo'];
$registrationNo = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_row()[0];
```

Basically, this dumps the array returned from the query into `fetch_row()`, and the `[0]` is accessing just the first element in that array.  Since you only specified a single field in your SQL, the first value in that array should be the data you want.

If you want to keep all of your code, you could just alter it this way:

```
$registrationNo = $result->fetch_row()[0];
```

Comment: Never, ever drop user-supplied data directly into a query.  Use prepared statements with placeholders for security reasons.